# Expressing infinite product as a series (formalizing Euler's proof of Basel problem)

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to formalize the step in the next image from Wikipedia's article about Euler's proof of Basel problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#Euler's_approach)

[image]

I've proven by induction that if we define $P_n(z)=\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1-\frac{z^2}{\pi^2}\right)$ then it is possible to express
$$P_n(z)=1- \dfrac{1}{\pi^2}\left( \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{k^2} \right)z^2+ \sum_{k=2}^n a_{k,n} z^{2k}$$
for some real numbers $a_{k,n}$.

Then, isolating the last sum and taking limits we get that

$$\dfrac{\sin(z)}{z}-1+\dfrac{1}{\pi^2}\left( \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k^2} \right)z^2=\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \sum_{k=2}^n a_{k,n} z^{2k}$$

So, I know that the last sum converges and I've tried to prove that $a_{k,n}$ converges to some $a_k$ for every $k\geq 2$ and that
\begin{align}{
\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \sum_{k=2}^n a_{k,n} z^{2k}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty a_{k} z^{2k} \hspace{10mm}(1)
}\end{align}

because if a I get that result, then

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} z^{2k}=\dfrac{\sin(z)}{z}=1-\dfrac{1}{\pi^2}\left( \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k^2} \right)z^2 + \sum_{k=2}^\infty a_{k} z^{2k}$$

and by the uniqueness of power series expansion, we can now compare the desired coefficients.

Any ideas on how to prove the convergence of the $a_{k,n}$ and (1)?

Or maybe, if there is an easier way of formaly proving we can compare the coefficients.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've thought another way of solving it.

As it can be shown by Weierstrass' factorization theorem and all that complex analysis machinery, $P_n$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, so as we have a sequence of analytic functions that converges uniformly on compact subsets, its derivatives also converges uniformly on compact subsets.

So, as we have that

$$P''_n(z)=-\dfrac{2}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{k^2}+(2k)(2k-1)\sum_{k=2}^n a_{k,n} z^{2(k-1)}$$

then

$$P''_n(0)=-\dfrac{2}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{k^2}$$

and so by means of the convergence we have ensure before, if we denote $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ then

$$f''(0)=-\dfrac{2}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k^2}$$

that was ultimately what we wanted to compare.